# D7 - form wsMaximized, but shows vertical scrollbar (only W8)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, maximize

I have a code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ....
    Left   := Screen.WorkAreaLeft;
    Top    := Screen.WorkAreaTop;
    Width  := Screen.WorkAreaWidth;
    Height := Screen.WorkAreaHeight;
    .....;
end;
```

W7 - displays correctly,
W8 - displays with vertical scrollbar

(see pictures)

[W7 - displays correctly]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIfm3.jpg)[image]

[W8 - displays with vertical scrollbar](http://www.imgup.cz/image/dZs)

[image]

Comment: Are you setting the size and position of the components that are placed on the form manually? Or are you using the alignments?

Comment: components are placed on the form with alignments